# Receive the percentage of zero counts

Tags: r

```
df <- data.frame(tid = c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3), aci = c(31122,0,491,31,0,0,0))
```

How is it possible to receive a percetange of 0 options per tid unique number.

```
data.frame(tid = c(1,2,3), aci_per = c(33.3,50,100))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can get the percentage by taking the `mean` of logical vector

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
     group_by(tid) %>% 
     summarise(aci_per = 100 *mean(aci == 0))
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#    tid aci_per
#  <dbl>   <dbl>
#1     1    33.3
#2     2    50  
#3     3   100
```

---

Or in `base R`

```
aggregate(cbind(aci_per = aci) ~ tid, df, FUN = function(x) 100 *mean(x == 0))
```

Comment: I do not get why the other answer would receive more upvotes than this answer

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% mutate(Flag=ifelse(aci==0,1,0)) %>% group_by(tid) %>%
  summarise(Per=paste0(100*round(mean(Flag==1),3),'%'))

# A tibble: 3 x 2
    tid Per  
  <dbl> <chr>
1     1 33.3%
2     2 50%  
3     3 100%
```